# Data from RadioButtons to SpannSelector, in matplotlib widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

Hello I am using the RadioButtons widget form matplotlib library, in python.

RadioButtons is updates a plot, after clicking and selecting option. Obviously RadioButtons distinguishes in concordance with a dictionary you define.

I need to pull the "selected, chosen" field to plotted using RadioButtons, because I need to do some post-processing of that selected field.

```
    def funcplot(label):
     plotdict = {'TBF': TBF, 'TTR': TTR, 'MTBF': MTBF, 'MTTR': MTTR, 'Avail': Avail}
     ydata = plotdict[label]
     l.set_ydata(ydata)
     plt.draw()
    radio.on_clicked(funcplot)
```

I am trying to pull from here the selected field:

```
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('TBF', 'TTR', 'MTBF', 'MTTR', 'Avail'))
```

Is it there any way to pull out ydata from the defined function?

Looking after your comments I salute everyone of you.-

Second part:

Thanks to the help the first part of the code is resumed as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, facecolor='gainsboro')
ax.set_title('Press left mouse button and drag to test')
l, = ax.plot(Time,TBF,'b-',label = 'TBF')
ax.set_ylabel('Valor')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('TBF', 'TTR', 'MTBF', 'MTTR', 'Avail'))

 plotdict = {'TBF': TBF, 'TTR': TTR, 'MTBF': MTBF, 'MTTR': MTTR, 'Avail': Avail}

def funcplot(label):
 l.set_ydata(plotdict[label])
 plt.draw()
radio.on_clicked(funcplot)
```

The selected field is stored as follows

```
label = radio.value_selected

y = plotdict[label]
```

What I wanted is to use y as entry for the SpannSelector called and defined as follows:

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, facecolor='gainsboro')
line2, = ax2.plot(x,y, 'bs-')
ax2.set_ylabel('Valor')
ax2.set_xlabel('Horas')


def onselect(xmin, xmax):
 indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
 indmax = min(len(x) - 1, indmax)

 thisx = x[indmin:indmax]
 thisy = y[indmin:indmax]
 line2.set_data(thisx, thisy)
 ax2.set_xlim(thisx[0], thisx[-1])
 ax2.set_ylim(thisy.min(), thisy.max())
 fig.canvas.draw()

# set useblit True on gtkagg for enhanced performance
span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red'))
```

The RadioButton selects the variable y, and the SpannSelector zooms the variable y. But when y changes due to clicks the SpannSelector remains as default

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The code you show should indeed plot the currently selected data. What is the problem with that? (Can you use a different word than "pull" and instead explain clearly what should happen upon what action?

Comment: I want to use the selected field, after making the click. I don't know where that option, variable is stored, so I can use after the click.

The code plots the selected field. yes, but assume that I want to perform further calculations with that field.

Comment: What do you mean by "use". You already use it in the code to select the data. Again, explain clearly what should happen upon what action? Use code to explain that.

Comment: ydata takes values of the selected field. But if after the call of the function I insert:

    print(radio.ydata)

Nothing appears. Assume I want to make an other plot with the selected field but in a different figure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currently selected label of a `RadioButtons` widget is stored in `RadioButtons.value_selected`. Hence you can access it at any point.

```
plotdict = {'TBF': TBF, 'TTR': TTR, 'MTBF': MTBF, 'MTTR': MTTR, 'Avail': Avail}
currentlabel = [None]

def funcplot(label):
    l.set_ydata(plotdict[label])
    currentlabel[0] = label
    plt.draw()

radio.on_clicked(funcplot)

### later...

plt.plot(plotdict[currentlabel[0]])
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there, the label assignment is well done, but the plotdict[label] comes up with errors.


y = plotdict[label]
NameError: name 'plotdict' is not defined

Comment: plotdict is defined in the very first line of code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the support and patience, Both of you

Comment: By the way one last thing. The label and field are apparently fixed in the default options.

If you click and select a new field, the statement: 

label = radio.value.selected

remains fixed with the first option. It was suppose to change interactively, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it should change. But please can you provide a [mcve], otherwise I have to write code from the top of my head without being able to test it; that makes things rather complicated for me.

Comment: Oks oks, there it goes

y = plotdict[label]
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, facecolor='gainsboro')
line2, = ax2.plot(x,y, 'bs-')
ax2.set_ylabel('Valor')
ax2.set_xlabel('Horas')

these last lines are used for the SpanSelector widget

Comment: See manually I can change y, and the SpanSelector gives me the zoom. But I want to try to mix the Radiobuttons with Spanselector...
The SpanSelector source can be found here [link](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/span_selector.html). The y value is an entry field, so it is suppose to be fixed... but after the RadioButtons I am suppose to change it at will.

Comment: What? Where is that SpanSelector suddenly coming from? Is it necessary for understanding the issue? Don't provide extensive code in the comments, update your question if necessary. A [mcve] should be in such a form that it can be copies, pasted and run.

Comment: I did not know it was possible to update the question. I will

Comment: Seems you want to use the same figure and update the value interactively. In that case you need to store it such that the `onselect` can find it.

Comment: Exactly the idea was to use the selected field, and Spann it after.